# A/B Testing - Can you trust the math with small samples?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Let's say I test a new version of my signup page. After the original and the variant each get 100 views, here are my results:

- Original had 1 conversion (1%), and a 95% confidence interval of 0-2.95%
- Variant had 5 conversions (5%), and a 95% confidence interval of 0.73-9.27%
  My p-value is 0.047502. So according to the math, I can be 95.2498% sure that the variant is better at some level than the original.

But is it?

Intuitively, I feel like the sample size is too small for 4 conversions to be significant. And I see articles on the internet saying I should wait for some minimum number of conversions. I wonder if it's just the imperfect human in me, or if the traditional statistical calculations are distorted at small sample sizes.

**Does anyone know if there is a problem with our formulas with small samples? If so, can you point me to any articles covering the topic?**

The calculation I'm using comes from VWO. You can get the same results from their [A/B Split Test Significance Calculator](https://vwo.com/ab-split-test-significance-calculator/) and see the formula in their [Excel version](https://vwo.com/blog/ab-testing-significance-calculator-spreadsheet-in-excel/).

Comment: "So according to the math, I can be 95.2498% sure that the variant is better at some level than the original." -- which mathematics says you can conclude that? I think you misunderstand what a p-value is.

Comment: I also can't reproduce your p-value. Are you using a normal approximation to a binomial or something? I think your expectations might be too small for that to work well and you don't seem to be using continuity correction (which should help some with the discreteness). Using a proportions test with continuity correction (`prop.test` in R) I get p=0.21. With a chi-squared test (Yates correction) I get excatly the same (which I'd expect). With simulation of the null distribution of the chi-square statistic given fixed margins, I get p=0.21. With Fisher's exact test, I get p=0.21.

Comment: In short, you should explain exactly which calculations you are performing.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding of a p-value. I just read an article, [How to Correctly Interpret P Values](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/how-to-correctly-interpret-p-values) that cleared it up.

Comment: I'm glad it helped, but some of the explanation there is also incorrect. For example, it says "*P values evaluate how well the sample data support the [...] argument that the null hypothesis is true*" --- p-values really don't do that! Fortunately, later on it gives the correct definition "*a P value is the probability of obtaining an effect at least as extreme as the one in your sample data, assuming the truth of the null hypothesis*"

Answer (score -1):

Partially answered in comments:

"So according to the math, I can be 95.2498% sure that the variant is better at some level than the original." -- which mathematics says you can conclude that? I think you misunderstand what a p-value is. – Glen_b

I also can't reproduce your p-value. Are you using a normal approximation to a binomial or something? I think your expectations might be too small for that to work well and you don't seem to be using continuity correction (which should help some with the discreteness). Using a proportions test with continuity correction (`prop.test` in R) I get p=0.21. With a chi-squared test (Yates correction) I get exactly the same (which I'd expect). With simulation of the null distribution of the chi-square statistic given fixed margins, I get p=0.21. With Fisher's exact test, I get p=0.21. – Glen_b

In short, you should explain exactly which calculations you are performing. – Glen_b

(   Thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding of a p-value. I just read an article, [How to Correctly Interpret P Values](https://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/how-to-correctly-interpret-p-values) that cleared it up. – Mike M. Lin   )

I'm glad it helped, but some of the explanation there is also incorrect. For example, it says "P values evaluate how well the sample data support the [...] argument that the null hypothesis is true" --- p-values really don't do that! Fortunately, later on it gives the correct definition "a P value is the probability of obtaining an effect at least as extreme as the one in your sample data, assuming the truth of the null hypothesis" – Glen_b

**Summary**: You really need a larger sample.